# AC Equivalent double nmos circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

Given the following circuit, I'm wondering about the \$ C_G \$ capacity in AC mode. Does it turn into a wire and disappear too because it's linked to GND?
Does it become something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The \$C_G\$ capacitor for an AC signal simply shorts out the M2 gate to GND. So that M2 could work as a common gate amplifier.
And the small signal model will look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFTSGD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: but where is R_1 ?

Comment: R1 for an AC signal is connected between two GND's.  The M2 gate is at GND due to C_G capacitor, and +5V is also a GND for AC signals. And this is why R1 sees GND from both sides.

Comment: but if you see, in your scheme R1 doesnt appear at all?

Comment: Yes, it does not appear because there is no AC component across R1. So what is the point of including the R1 into the AC equivalent circuit if there is no AC current flowing through it?  Only DC current is flowing through R1.

Comment: Neither does R_d

Comment: Why is R_2 the one in the gate of M1? instead of R_3?

Comment: What? The R2 and R3 are shown on the small signal equivalent circuit. So what is the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149128/discussion-between-mohamed-salhi-and-g36).